# Vertical alignment of subfigures LATEX

Tags: image, latex, formatting, vertical-alignment

I am working on my thesis and I am struggling with placing 2 images next to each other, so that the second image would be centered vertically along the first one. I was also trying to use `subfigure` instead of `subfloat` but neither of them works.

This is how it looks [alt text http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/1174/screenshot20100224at712.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/1174/screenshot20100224at712.png)

and my code is:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering  \subfloat[H][sparse($\mathbf{A}$)]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{sparsesmall} \label{sparse}}
    \subfloat[H][full($\mathbf{A}$)]{\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{fullsmall}\label{full}}
  \caption{Representation of $\mathbf{A}$ in MATLAB}
  \label{schematic}
\end{figure}
```

Any suggestions to make it look better than now? Thx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Edit*: it seems like `subfig` package has problems, particularly when working with hyperref.  In that case, try `subcaption` package as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795247/226621).

If you use `subfig` package, you can do this easily.  The solution is in section 5.4 of [the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf):

```
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{figure}[H]
\sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{sparsesmall}}
\subfloat[sparse($\mathbf{A}$)]{\usebox{\tempbox}\label{sparse}}%
\qquad
\subfloat[full($\mathbf{A}$)]{\vbox to \ht\tempbox{%
  \vfil
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{fullsmall}
  \vfil}\label{full}}%
  \caption{Representation of $\mathbf{A}$ in MATLAB}\label{schematic}
\end{figure}
```

I haven't tested it, and there may be typos, but it should work.

Comment: For some reason the caption of the second figure is aligned to right. Otherwise it works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: FYI, the `subfig` package is outdated now. So, the answer with `subcaption` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795247/8653606) should be used instead.

Answer (score 52):

You can also use `\raisebox{x}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}` where `x` is negative to shift it downwards and positive to shift upwards.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution (which works with the `subcaption` package is

```
\begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Large Picture}
            \includegraphics{LARGEPIC}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{SMALL PIC}
            \includegraphics{small picture}
            \begin{minipage}{.1cm}
            \vfill
            \end{minipage}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \caption{Two pictures}
\end{figure}
```

The `\vfill` alone does not work, that's why it is put into the `minipage`

Comment: Thanks, I cannot use subfig package so this is the way to go (For me at least).

Answer (score 3):

My method is using square minipage which centers its contents:

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Figure a]{%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{0.5\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[clip,width=1\textwidth]{figurea}%
\end{minipage}}\subfloat[Figure b]{\centering{}%
\begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{0.5\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[clip,width=0.6\textwidth]{figureb}
\par\end{center}%
\end{minipage}}
\caption{main caption}
\end{figure}
```

This code was generated by LyX, however, so it's a bit ugly.